# Efficiently remove duplicate elements from the list

Tags: c#

I have a legacy code in which `ids` List has some duplicate value coming and this method is being called from lot of difference places as of now -

```
public async Task<List<T>> Execute<T>(IList<int> ids, Policy policy, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc) where T : class
{
    var holder = new List<Task<T>>(ids.Count);
    var removeNull = new List<T>(ids.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
    {
        var id = ids[i];
        holder.Add(ProcessData(policy, ct => mapperFunc(ct, id)));
    }

    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(holder);
    for (int i = 0; i < responses.Length; i++)
    {
        var response = responses[i];
        if (response != null)
        {
            removeNull.Add(response);
        }
    }
    return removeNull;
}
```

I am trying to change above method such that I can remove duplicate stuff from `ids` list so I came up with below code which does that but I wanted to see if there is any better way we can write below code?

```
public async Task<List<T>> Execute<T>(IList<int> ids, Policy policy, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc) where T : class
{
    var noDupsList = new HashSet<int>(ids).ToList();
    var holder = new List<Task<T>>(noDupsList.Count);
    var removeNull = new List<T>(noDupsList.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < noDupsList.Count; i++)
    {
        var id = noDupsList[i];
        holder.Add(ProcessData(policy, ct => mapperFunc(ct, id)));
    }

    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(holder);
    for (int i = 0; i < responses.Length; i++)
    {
        var response = responses[i];
        if (response != null)
        {
            removeNull.Add(response);
        }
    }
    return removeNull;
}
```

**Update**

Seeing the answer that came I thought it's good idea to mention how my actual code is - This is how my original code is :

```
public async Task<List<T>> Execute<T>(IList<int> ids, Policy policy, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc, string logMessage) where T : class
{
    var noDupsList = new HashSet<int>(ids).ToList();
    var holder = new List<Task<T>>(noDupsList.Count);
    var removeNull = new List<T>(noDupsList.Count);
    using (var logMetric = new LogMetric(_logger, TITLE, "DatabaseCall"))
    {
        logMetric.Message = logMessage;
        for (int i = 0; i < noDupsList.Count; i++)
        {
            var id = noDupsList[i];
            holder.Add(ProcessData(policy, ct => mapperFunc(ct, id)));
        }

        var responses = await Task.WhenAll(holder);
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.Length; i++)
        {
            var response = responses[i];
            if (response != null)
            {
                removeNull.Add(response);
            }
        }
        logMetric.StatusCode = (removeNull.Count == 0) ? 204 : 200;
    }
    return removeNull;
}
```

Comment: Use `Linq` it will shorten your code and give you more readability to your code. For instance, `var uniqueIdsList = ids.Distinct().ToList();`  would give you the unique ids directly.

Comment: Is `Linq` efficient here? I have been told its quite expensive and this method will be called at hight throughput so just wanted to make sure. But apart from that do you think we can rewrite this in better way to solve this problem or just change that one line to use linq instead of set?

Comment: `Linq` is efficient in mostly, it would do the same thing, except it would be shorter, readable, and extendable. You can try to test it, and see how it would preform with the reset of the code. Compare, then decide.

Comment: The problem of given you a decent answer here, is that I have no idea what `ProcessData` actually should do, neither do I know whether you can change the signature of your method. I would quite possibly keep the return type to `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` or `Task<IReadonlyList<T>>` if I have to, and the input type restricted to `IEnumerable<int> ids`. To be fair you can wrap the entire code in 1 somewhat long one liner with linq with using a `Select` (to get the tasks) and a `Where` (to filter out the nulls). Is performance a must here?

Comment: Where is `logMessage` coming? Do you really want to log a number here? If you really need to know if nulls got removed, I guess you could check the hashset length vs the filtered responses length, but I am not getting the logic here completely

Comment: sorry updated my code to add `logMessage`. I missed it earlier. It is just our own way of logging. I just want to wrap that in the same way it is there right now. @Icepickle

Comment: To be fair, I don't think logging should be part of this at all, couldn't this be done with a layer in between? I am assuming there is some dependency injection being done in this code (though the logging as it stands, might indicate there is not), so why not use something like a decorator/adapter pattern for the logging? That way, you can keep your efficient `Execute` method, but if you need logging, you could turn it on

Comment: That logging is our internal framework which calculates average latency and few other things on its own because that call is what we made to database so we are calculating it for metrics purpose. Also that logging does few other things that we can see like qps, latency and few other things.

Comment: That should make a big difference, I believe, you could just make it so that you have an adapter that does the logging for you, but then calls your real Execute method before and after the logging (as you would have the ids & the responses, you could check in the adapter what the differences were afterwards) I am just trying to say that I can't see the logging as part of the responsibility of the Execute method

Comment: yeah make sense. I will look into that and see if I can refactor it in future release but for now what will be the best way to adapt to it with your current answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you used a good way to filter out the duplicates, but I don't see why you feel the need to call `.ToList()` after that. A `HashSet` is perfectly iterable.

As such, I believe I would write your lengthy code somewhat differently as:

```
public async Task<IReadonlyList<T>> Execute<T>(IEnumerable<int> ids, Policy policy, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc) where T : class 
{
    return (await Task.WhenAll(
            new HashSet<int>(ids).Select( id => ProcessData( policy, ct => mapperFunc( ct, id ) ) ) ) )
        .Where( response => response != null )
        .ToList();
}
```

It will still remove all the duplicates, await all entries using the `Task.WhenAll` and remove the `null` values.

As for knowing if it is more efficient I can't tell without testing. I think it is more readable, though to be fair, I would probably rather assign the results to a variable before filtering them out, saving you some brackets.

```
public async Task<IReadonlyList<T>> Execute<T>(IEnumerable<int> ids, Policy policy, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc) where T : class 
{
    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(
            new HashSet<int>(ids).Select( id => ProcessData( policy, ct => mapperFunc( ct, id ) ) ) );

    return responses
        .Where( response => response != null )
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can update my question which has `ProcessData` method as well so that it can clear your confusion if needed but I have a question on your suggestion. Will this have any problem related to closure issue? Earlier I had closure issue with my original code so that's why I needed to initialize variable like this - `var id = ids[i];` to fix that so just making sure your suggestion will not have same problem?

Comment: @AndyP, No you shouldn't have a problem there, `id` is already local because of the lambda in select

Comment: After checking your answer which I think is really good I was gonna try integrating in my solution but I realize one thing. I removed one thing from my original code which I thought is not relevant here but looking at your answer now I am confuse on how to have that in your suggestion. So I updated my question to provide my full code which has this line `using (var logMetric = new LogMetric(_logger, TITLE, "DatabaseCall"))` wrapped around my first for loop.

Comment: I apologize about this as I should have added this in earlier. Now with that detail can we still use your suggestion or we need to change it? If yes, then how I can wrap around using block in your suggestion? Will it be wrapped around `var responses` block?

Comment: @AndyP yes, wrap it inside the usings or use a local using statement

Comment: Can you update this in your answer as well please if possible?